# copy then delete safe workaround

Tags: bash, file, unix, copy

Since seems like copy files across 2 directory (**1 mounted and 1 not**) doesn't work
(I've tried using **UTL_FILE.FRENAME**, asking here and also on asktom but no one actually could help me)

I've decided to use a workaround:

**COPY then DELETE**, in terms of exception, what problems could merge?
Is this a safe operation, I mean a solid-rock solution?
(UTL_FILE.FCOPY then UTL_FILE.FREMOVE)

Or it's better to do behind some bash scripting like **mv**

Thanks

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but wouldn't both directories need to be mounted for just about any process to copy files between them. Its surely not surprising that Oracle can't do it and I'd be surprised to see any UNIX command do it without first mounting the FS the directory is on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323652/utl-file-rename-operation-failed

My old question